# Is subscr_eot sent if I refund the subscriber payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Does subscr_eot IPN notification get sent if I refund the payment halfway through the subscriber period?

Comment: Good question. I would suspect so. I imagine you would have to do more than just refund to get the subscripton completely cancelled. Let's hope the Paypal guys here respond.